# Why we need @types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am new to typescript and decided to install and work with Lodash. Then, I found out that I needed to install `@types/lodash` which is TypeScript version of Lodash (I hope I am right). Is it true that we need to install javascript version of Lodash first in order to use `@types/lodash`?

Answer (score 6):

You do not have to install @types/lodash package, however, it is good to install it. The package contains type definitions, so your IDE can smartly hint you and you will be able to strictly define types for parameters etc.

To be accurate, @types/lodash is not a TypeScript version of Lodash - it is only package with type definitions, so you have to install Loadash via `npm i --save lodash` to be able to use it and optionally download the type package.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactely

You can use [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) directly https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

Comment: Hi @GRF, it appears you've misunderstood the question. The OP is already using lodash directly. The question is about effective use within TypeScript.

Comment: hmm ok, thanks for the clarification @aggregate1166877